# navigating between 2 views with dropdownlist using jQuery asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

window.location.href can not navigate to the view i choosed

here is my js :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submitButton').click(function () {

        var temp = $("#dropDownList option:selected").val();

        if (temp == "person")
            window.location.href = "http://localhost:1284/Home/Person";
        if (temp == "job")
            window.location.href = "http://localhost:1284/Home/Job";
    });

});
</script>

@Html.BeginForm()

    <select id="dropDownList">
        <option value="person">Person</option>
        <option value="job">Job</option>
    </select>

    <button id="submitButton">Choose</button>
```

can i use @html.actionlink ?? or any other solution

Answer (score 0):

you do not need @Html.BeginForm(), this submits the current page to itself...So, following should work..

```
 <div>
   <select id="dropDownList">
    <option value="person">Person</option>
    <option value="job">Job</option>
  </select>
 <button id="submitButton">Choose</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submitButton').click(function () {

      var temp = $("#dropDownList option:selected").val();
      if (temp == "person") window.location.href = "http://localhost:1284/Home/Person";
      if (temp == "job")  window.location.href = "http://localhost:1284/Home/Job";

     });
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the responsibility of the controller to decide the view to render. You have to set the Url redirection for the controller's action rather than the view itself.

Here is how you could generate this url using a server side helper `@Url.Action` in javascript.

```
$(function () {
  $('#submitButton').click(function () {

    var temp = $("#dropDownList option:selected").val();

    var urlPerson = '@Url.Action("Person", "Home")'; // Home:Controller, Person:Action
    var urlJob = '@Url.Action("Job", "Home")'; // Home:Controller, Job:Action

    if (temp == "person")
        window.location = urlPerson;
    if (temp == "job")
        window.location = urlJob;
  });
});
```

`'@Html.ActionLink'` will generate the whole `<a>` tag

```
var result = '@Html.ActionLink("Link", "Person", "Home")';
```

The above code will generate

```
<a href="/Home/Person">Link</a>
```